# angular-translate: How to load static json files?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ionic-framework, angular-translate

**THE SITUATION:**

I am using [angular-translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) for my app.

Everything was working perfectly. But i just needed to move the translations into static json files.

I have followed all the instructions but is not working.

**THE CODE (BEFORE):**

```
$translateProvider.translations('en', {

    "WELCOME": "Welcome",
});

$translateProvider.translations("tr", {

    "WELCOME": "Hoşgeldiniz",
});

$translateProvider.translations("it", {

    "WELCOME": "Benvenuto",
});
```

**THE CODE (NOW):**

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: '/translations/',
    suffix: '.json'
});
```

**JSON FILES:**

path:

```
www/translations/en.json

www/translations/it.json

www/translations/tr.json
```

Example:

```
{
    "WELCOME": "Benvenuto",
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token } in JSON at position 4160
at Object.parse (native)
```

**THE QUESTION:**

How can i load the translations from static json using angular-translate?

What can be wrong in my case?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know which file triggers the error? If not try them one by one and look what is at position 4160. Should be a `}` too much

Comment: That's the point. I cannot debug it. In the console it just point to: at fromJson (http://localhost:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9892:14)

Comment: Open the json file, copy everything into chrome console and look at the errors, change file accordingly, rinse and repeat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Removing char ',' at the end of key definition in your json. It make json parser try to read next char '}' as new key and error raised

Comment: Oh my god! You are right! Hours crashing the head against the wall and was a comma in the end of the file... Thanks!